# What does a real-time server return in response for an Angular App?

Tags: angular

I have just started learning Angular . I wanted to understand what fundamental problems in DOM manipulation or Browser rendering does Angular Solve or was purported to solve .

I was going through the tutorial in the following official page :

https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt0

I could follow the creation of components and all . But what I wanted to understand is the full picture of what the backend server does  when a web page is meant to be run as one such angular app .

So instead of filling these questions with my ignorance and making the questin unclear , the following are the questions I need help with :

1. Let's say a http server like in the following pseudo-code is written  :

tuple_for_url_view = ( "/" , "some_html.txt") ;

```
var n = createhttpserver( 8080 , tuple_for_url_view);


n.start() ;
```

Now  the above is a pseudo-code  for a http server which when contacted with a URL with only the domain name returns an html response which is stored in a file called "some_hmtl.txt" .

Now for such an angular app to be run in the client when the server is contacted what is the response returned by the server ?

I went through the following link as well :

https://dev.to/casperns/how-angular-trigger-indexhtml-and-start-working-1l46

But still I am not clear , what does the backend server return in response , "main.ts"  or "index.html"  or "app.component.html " ?

How does the browser then run this application exactly, like it runs when ng --serve is executed, from the contents of whatever out of these above files is returned

2. What happens at the browser side ? Does the browser request for all these files from the server so as to run this application ?

Comment: usually the backend server returns the index.html which then references the main.js which does all the heacy lifting. main.ts and app.component.ts dont exist anymore at this point since they get transpiled to javascript

Comment: During build process (in ex. with the command `ng build`) by default compiled app will be in `/dist` directory. You should upload content of that directory to your server. By default configuration, the server will send content of `index.html` to the user browser and then browser will load JS files listed in `index.html` (`main.js`, `runtime.js` and so on). After that Angular will also load other lazy modules if needed.
So, you have to upload just content of `/dist`.

Comment: @jonathanHeindl : Is main.js returned by the server ? Could you elaborate a bit on what does the browser do with the index.html and the role of main.js ? Where does the obtained transpiled code get attached ?

Comment: @Lyczos : So , the browser parses the content of index.html and from there it makes request for files in "dist" folder of the server so as to get the resources like "main.js" , "runtime.js"  ?

Comment: Just do `ng build` and look at what it produce. There's a lot of stuff going on in the bundle js files, if you want to understand how all those templating works it's all available on angular's github.

Comment: The thing to remember is that the server neither knows nor cares that the browser is running Angular.  When you as a developer write your app, you then transpile it, which results in ".html" files that contain the angular tags "<app-root>",etc plus "<script" tags specifying the angular runtime.  When your browser requests the ".html" file, the server will serve this up (just like any other html), and your browser therefore requests and runs those "<script" files (again as normal), and those js scripts pick up / process those angular tags.

Comment: @racraman : That makes me wonder , why to build the app somewhere else rather than having the browser's runtime code to do all the magic by understanding ng-tags or whatever domain-specific-language-tokens  are there ..

Comment: It is because before build (during the development process) code has to be readable for the programmer. During build process code is optimized, obfuscated and compressed. Also, because angular using Typescript code can be checked when build is in progress(you can catch error before you run the app on client side).